# Generating a pair of letter from a given sequence

Tags: python

I have a problem to be solved and I would appreciate if anyone can help. I want to generate all possible two-letters string from the given sequence. For example from string 'ACCG', I want to generate a list of [AA, CC, GG, AC,CA,AG,GA,CG,GC].

Does anyone have an idea how I can do that ?

Comment: How would you do this by hand? Think about the steps you would take to generate these pairs. Then try to describe those steps in English.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generating all possible combinations of characters in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45990454/generating-all-possible-combinations-of-characters-in-a-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An efficient solution can be coded using `itertools` module

**CODE**

```
import itertools

string = 'ACCG'
num = 2

combinations = list(itertools.product(string, repeat=num))
result = [*set([''.join(tup) for tup in combinations])]

print(result)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
['CG', 'GG', 'GC', 'GA', 'AG', 'AA', 'CC', 'AC', 'CA']
```

Comment: Consider using `itertools.product` not `itertools.permutations` because he needs to include repeating characters such as `AA`. The correct way: `print(list(itertools.product("ACCG", repeat=2)))`

Comment: @Jeffrey rather `[''.join(x) for x in itertools.product(set('ACCG'), repeat=2)]` to directly avoid the duplicates ;)

Comment: @vignesh the use of intermediate lists is inefficient. See my above comment for a cleaner way.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a one-liner (using *product* from itertools) then try this:

```
from itertools import product

out = [''.join(p) for p in set(product('ACCG', repeat=2))]

print(out)
```

**Output:**

```
['AA', 'GG', 'CC', 'GA', 'AC', 'CG', 'GC', 'CA', 'AG']
```